# Flushing data again and again to memory or writing it to log and then flushing to main memory for write intensive workload?

Tags: memory, memory-management, io, operating-system, disk

Consider i have a **write intensive application** which, now i want to design the system to write back the modified data to memory, i can use either policy-

1. write it to a log file and then as it gets filled i can write this block to the main memory
2. i can flush the complete block after the data gets modified
   which policy will be better ?

and what if my application is **read intensive** with less number of data modifications should i go with first policy or second policy ?

Comment: This might be useful: [Memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)

Comment: i read it, but unfortunately i wasn't looking for it exactly, i was not clear, i want to know which policy to go for if i have write intensive and read intensive workload.